# Parse localized DateTime before save to database in ruby or rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, internationalization

Is it possible to parse a localized DateTime string back to a proper DateTime using native 
Ruby or Rails methods?

I looked in i18n where I would expect this to be, since it holds the formats and locale, but I couldn't find it.

I have a String: `"za 18 mei 18:05"` which is Dutch (`:nl`), in English it would be `"Sa 18 May 6:15PM"`.The dateformat is: `"%a %d %b %H:%M"`. I want the String to parse back to `2012-05-08T18:12:00+01:00`.

Is there a possible way to get a DateTime from this? I have a large locale file for my Dutch translations and I can't imagine I cannot use this to parse a format back to db format

Comment: Wait, is your locale :nl? What happens when you do: `Date.today.strftime '%a %d %b %H:%M'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to manipulate your date strings a little bit, because they are not in English.

Try this:

```
nl = "vri 18 mei 18:05"
dt = DateTime.strptime(nl.gsub(/vri|mei/, 'vri' => 'Fri', 'mei' => 'May'), "%a %d %b %H:%S")
```

That is an example approach on how to replace 'za' with 'Sat' and 'mei' with 'May' before sending the string to `strptime`. You probably need to come up with a more elegant approach on replacing your original strings (writing a helper for example).

**Using the `delocalize` gem**

Alternatively, maybe you can try the gem `delocalize`:

```
I18n.locale = :nl
Delocalize::LocalizedDateTimeParser.parse("Vri 18 mei 18:02", DateTime)
```

Make sure that you have the correct "nl.yml" in your `config/locales` folder.
You can grab from here: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/nl.yml

Comment: isn't there a way to do this with i18n? It holds the used formats and translations. I already use it to get a localized date from a DateTime, I just want to convert the localized version back to a DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at https://github.com/carlosantoniodasilva/i18n_alchemy it works in a similar fashion to delocalize but its scope is limited to models so it does not mess with the view classes.